# After upgraded my Angular project from Angular9 to 17, featue.component.html got a bunch of "Property is not provided" errors

Tags: angular17

After upgraded my Angular project from Angular9 to 17, in the feature.component.html, I got below errors:
Property formGroup is not provided by any applicable directives nor by form element
Property ngIf is not provided by any applicable directive on an embedded template
Property ngValue is not provided by any applicable directives nor by option element
Property ngForOf is not provided by any applicable directive on an embedded template
There is no directive with 'exportAs' set to ngbAccordion
Property ngStyle is not provided by any applicable directives nor by div element
The project worked perfectly with Angular 9, meaning it has all mechanism in place for Angular.

I use module style.
main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import 'hammerjs';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^17.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "@ngx-pwa/local-storage": "^17.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@v6/v6-details-summary": "7.0.0",
    "@v6/v6-icons": "6.0.2",
    "@v6/v6-navigation": "7.0.0",
    "@v6/v6-other-components": "7.2.0",
    "@v6/v6-pipes": "7.1.0",
    "@v6/v6-services": "7.1.0",
    "@v6/v6-table": "^8.1.4",
    "@v6/v6-themes": "6.0.3",
    "@v6/v6-toast": "7.0.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "28.2.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "28.2.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "28.2.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.17.0",
    "angular-svg-icon": "^17.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "5.3.2",
    "esbuild": "^0.19.9",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^1.0.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.202",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  }
```

I tried to create feature.module.js to import the FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule but didn't help.
I also run "ng g @angular/core:control-flow", only got worse.